# Google App Engine standard environment to Cloud-SQL Second Generation instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I consider starting a PHP project in App Engine and would like to use Cloud 2SQL in the second generation.

Now I am confused if this is possible or not, since I have found different information on the google sites.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

> Note: Access to Google Cloud SQL Second Generation instances can be granted only for apps running in the flexible environment. Learn more.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/dev-access

> App Engine **standard environment** to a Second Generation instance
>   You connect from Google App Engine standard environment) to Second Generation instances by completing the following steps:

- Granting the application access (if required)
- Updating your application to provide the appropriate connection string.

Is it now possible or not?

Comment: You caught the docs in the middle of being updated. I think things should be clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use Cloud SQL v2 on App Engine standard.

Check out Terrance Ryan's (Developer Advocate for GCP) blog post on this topic [0], more specifically:

"If you are an App Engine customer and looked at v2 before, it did not support App Engine. However, that appears to have changed: you can now access Cloud SQL v2 from App Engine standard environment, or App Engine flexible environment."

[0] http://terrenceryan.com/blog/index.php/cloud-sql-v1-vs-v2/

Comment: Great, thank you for the link. Of course I have googled before, but this article did not show up.